# Will the RDMA enabled NIC do endian conversion?

Tags: infiniband, rdma, mellanox

Is it possible to get an RDMA adapter (e.g. Mellanox NIC) to do an endian conversion during data transfer?  Specifically, we're doing an RDMA transfer from a big-endian to a little-endian system and vice versa.  Once data lands at the target, then we need to do a bswap32() or bswap64() to do the endian conversion which will chew processor cycles.  I am wondering if we can get free bswaps from the NIC instead.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping endianness is not an operation/attribute that is defined in the InfiniBand spec.
However, Mellanox devices (ConnectX-4 and up) do provide look-aside vector calculation primitives, with endianity swap as one of the operations supported.
This essentially means that one may be able to perform this look-aside HW swap on the data before sending it or after receiving it.

This vector calculation capability is still in its early stages in terms of exposure to higher-level APIs. You will be able to find some references in these Linux kernel commits:

- https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8365791/ ([rdma-next,3/8] net/mlx5_core: Introduce offload arithmetic hardware capabilities)
- https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8388951/ ([rdma-next,V1,7/8] IB/core: Advertise supported vector CALC capabilities)

Partial support is also available through the "experimental verbs" on Mellanox OFED - keep watching for updates to come.